# Modal notification box on the screen of every authenticated user

Tags: notifications, actions, privatemsg, rules

I want that every time I or any other admin (I have 2 more) post a new article each authenticated user should get a modal notification box on it's screen displaying a teaser of the Content Type I have posted.

I created an action 'Display a message to the user' for the trigger, 'TRIGGER: AFTER SAVING NEW CONTENT' and then tried saving new content and checked on a different account (which was already logged) for any message but nothing happened. Also, if this worked I'd like to show a modal box with the display settings (which I have in place already).

Answer (score 0):

Drupal does not provide a way to send notifications to all site users by default. The action you are trying to use will only notify the user who triggers the action (you). [Messaging](https://drupal.org/project/messaging) can help you achieve what you want. You may also need the appbar module.